# AT&T email to text shows CSS snippets

Tags: text, sms, att

My company sends alerts to users who have opted in to receive SMS text alerts. These are sent through email to text gateway for user's carrier. All networks except AT&T show text message corrects. COntents are exactly what was sent. In AT&T text messages, there is extra CSS snippets that is showing after the message. You can view screen capture at https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bj1biFclQhoknVL3-ruNppPHAZRoQGBE. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Our emails are sent through Sendgrid for all carriers. I don't think its Sendgrid issue since text messages for other carriers show fine, without any additional text as in AT&T messages.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. Its is due to Sendgrid including tracking image. We are now sending filters using X-SMTPAPI header to disable tracking. AT&T users are not seeing that extra CSS anymore.